# how to count non empty cells in macro

Tags: vba, excel, cell

Hi i have come up with a code to open multiple workbooks. The code is

```
Sub OPEN_hari()
Dim r As Long
For r = 1 To 10
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sheet2.Cells(r, 1).Value
Next r
End Sub
```

But the problem here is if only 3 cells ((1,1) (2,1) (3,1)) has the path of the workbook files, an error message is thrown that coulndt open "" files.
How can i make this macro to open only the files that are mentioned without error message.
As i am beginner in this any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using `If..Then` to check there's a value in the cell?

Comment: No Tim :( Can you please Help me with this??

Comment: Thanks tim I tried with if...then its working fine the code is 
If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then

Answer (score 1):

There're two ways of getting what you need:

1. Run an infinite loop, checking the emptiness of a cell:

   ```
   Dim i as Long: i = 0 

   While Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1)) 'assuming the value is in Column A
       'your code
       i = i + 1 
   Wend
   ```
2. Get the number of used rows, however there's a risk that a cell might have been used, but is have no data now, so I'm including a check:

   ```
   Dim ur as Long: ur = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   Dim i as Long

   For i = 0 to (ur - 1)
        If LenB(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value) > 0 then
           'your code
        End If 
   Next i
   ```