# For loop in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to use For loop on an excel column. This is my code:

```
   For Each c In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A5000").Cells
        c.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Value = Right((Left(c, 13)), 7)
   Next
```

it works ok the problem is with the

```
Range("A1:A5000")
```

my sheet has less then 1000 rows but it can grow and I want to be able to use the loop only on the rows that have data in them. 
how can I change it to go from  A1 to the last not empty row?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/114493/11683

Comment: Within the loop, your `.Range("A1")` is redundant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770574/how-to-count-non-empty-cells-in-macro/15771514#15771514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this ...

```
Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("A65536").End(xlup)

For Each c In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:" & r.Address).Cells
   c.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Value = Right((Left(c, 13)), 7)
Next
```

Comment: Should be `Set r = Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlup)` to handle xl07 and onwards - the current formula was appropriate for xl03 and earlier but many more rows now.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim RowIndex As Long
RowIndex = 1

Dim c

While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(RowIndex, 1))
    Set c = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(RowIndex, 1)
    c.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Value = Right((Left(c, 13)), 7)
    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
Wend
```