# VBA column looping

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a large Excel file and I need to replace all values in 12 columns completely.

Right now, there is a formula in each one of the cells, and I need to replace that formula with my own.

How do I loop through all those columns, knowing at what row it starts but don't know the end row (file is updated constantly). The hack of "A600000" seems overkill.

I am new to VBA and some guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: you generally don't want to loop if you can avoid it (by using ranges for instance, or specialcells, or filters, etc.). First things first: What are you trying to replace the formulas with?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17896655/11683

Comment: what is the original formula(s) and what do you want to replace them with. Depending on the format of the formula, this could be done in several steps outside of VBA by just using find and replace

Comment: It is a =APF($Jxx, "string1", "string2") and I want to replace 12 columns (not one after another) to =RDT("prog.id", ,"string1", $Jxx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange` is the range of all the used cells on the current sheet.
You can use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` and `.Columns.Count` to get the height and widht of this range.

Here's a very crude function that hits every cell in the range:

```
Sub test()
    Dim thisRange As Range
    Set thisRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    With thisRange
        For y = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For x = 1 To .Columns.Count
                thisRange.Cells(y, x).Value = "Formula here"
            Next x
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

But what you want may be different, can you be more specific?

Comment: It is a =APF($Jxx, "string1", "string2") and I want to replace 12 columns (not one after another) to =RDT("prog.id", ,"string1", $Jxx).

Comment: Can you count on your columns being equal length, or is this unknown?

Comment: I'm not fully sure, but I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: Wally, your answer did solve the question, but there is much more to my part, so kudos and accepted =)

Answer (score 1):

The below will accomplish what you need to do.  You just need to supply the `startRow`, `.Sheets("Name")`, and `i` arguments.  If the columns are all the same length, then `UsedRange` will work fine if there are not random cells with values outside and below the columns you are interested in.  Otherwise, try this in your code (on a throw away copy of your workbook)

```
Sub GetLastRowInColumn()

Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Activeworkbook.Sheets("YOURSHEETNAMEHERE")

Dim startRow as long
    startRow = 1

Dim lastRow as long

Dim i as long    
For i = 1 to 12 'Column 1 to Column 12 (Adjust Accordingly)

    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row  
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, i), ws.Cells(lRow, i)).Formula = "=Max(1)"  'Sample Formula

Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT : Fixed typo**

The below function will build the range with varying length columns.  Use the function to return the desired range and fill all related cells in one shot.

```
Function GetVariantColumnRange(MySheet As Excel.Worksheet, _
      TopRow As Long, StartColumn As Long, LastColumn As Long) As Excel.Range

Dim topAddress As String
Dim bottomAddress As String

Dim addressString As String

Dim i As Long
For i = StartColumn To LastColumn

     topAddress = MySheet.Cells(TopRow, i).Address
     bottomAddress = MySheet.Cells(MySheet.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Address
     addressString = addressString & ", " & topAddress & ":" & bottomAddress

Next

addressString = Right(addressString, Len(addressString) - _ 
                 InStr(1, addressString, ", ", vbBinaryCompare))

Set GetVariantColumnRange = MySheet.Range(addressString)

End Function
```

Usage follows...

```
Sub Test()

Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = GetVariantColumnRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1), 1, 1, 12)

myrange.Select 'Just a visual aid.  Remove from final code.
myrange.Formula = "=APF($Jxx, "string1", "string2") "

End Sub
```